# Is it good practice to have heavy use of static member variables?

Tags: c++

As somebody without any formal training in programming, I'd like to know whether my C++ coding approach is considered good practice. Specifically, I am talking about the use of classes whose members are all static. This is a model which I use frequently, for cases when I know for certain that the class will only be instantiated once, and I want to be able to access that class from anywhere in my code. However, it tends to look a little odd because of the vast number of `static` keywords around, and the fact that I have to explicitly initialise these variables outside the class definition.

For example, if I am writing a game, there may be several classes which I instantiate just once and want to access from anywhere. These classes could be `Graphics`, to represent the colours and shapes to render, `World`, to represent the world in which my characters live, `User`, to represent the current human player of the game, `Score`, to represent the current score, etc. I would typically create these as "static" classes, because then I can access them from anywhere in my code. If they were "non-static" classes, then I would have to keep passing around pointers to these objects.

So, for a football game, my code might look like:

```
// world.h

class World
{
public:
  static float pitch_colour;
  static float pitch_size;
  static float player_colour;
  static float player_size;
  static int num_players;
  static std::vector<Player> players;

  static void UpdatePositions();
};



// world.cpp

float World::pitch_colour = 0.9;
float World::pitch_size = 100;
float World::player_colour = 0.3;
float World::player_size = 5;
int World::num_players = 10;
std::vector<Player> World::players = std::vector<Player>(World::num_players);

void World::UpdatePositions()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_players; i++)
    {
        players[i].UpdatePosition();
    }
}



// main.cpp

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        World::UpdatePositions();
        Graphics::DrawPitch(World::pitch_size, World::pitch_colour);
        for (int i = 0; i < World::num_players; i++)
        {
            Graphics::DrawPlayer(&World::players[i], World::player_size, World::player_colour);
        }
     }
 }
```

This kind of code runs fine, but I'm just wondering whether using lots of static classes like this is a typical approach, or whether there is something more highly recommended? Thanks!

Comment: I think you forgot to actually declare them as static.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks...!! I've just fixed it....

Comment: I would say this is NOT recommended. Although SO closes opinionated questions..

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to group global variables/functions (as you seem to actually be doing here) just put them inside a namespace.

OTOH, what you seem to be doing looks a lot like the singleton pattern, here you can find some suggestions and a ton of links/dupes:

[C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern)